# Rsync to remote server with mounted NFS USB

Tags: ssh, nfs, rsync

I am trying to rsync one file from server X to server Y.
In the server Y, there is a mounted dir /mnt/myDir, where I am trying to sync that file. The goal is also to keep the full path of the file.

I am trying to do this with:

```
sudo -u www-data rsync -avz /var/www/dms/test/test.tif user@server.com:/mnt/myDir/var/www/dms/test/test.tif
```

But this is triggering the following error:

```
sending incremental file list
rsync: change_dir#3 "/mnt/myDir/var/www/dms/test" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: errors selecting input/output files, dirs (code 3) at main.c(643) [Receiver=3.0.9]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (241 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error arise from the fact you are trying to sync into a directory which does not exist on the remote side.

You have the following possibilities:

- first create the dir on the target directory issuing `mkdir /mnt/myDir/var/www/dms/test` (on the remote side), then issue your `rsync` command
- elaborating on that, if you need to transfer the entire `/var/www` directory, you need to create the remote `/mnt/myDir/var/www` dir and the issuing something similar to `sudo -u www-data rsync -avz /var/www/ user@server.com:/mnt/myDir/var/www`
- alternatively, you can instruct `rsync` to do the entire work for you, using the `-R` (`--relative`) option and issuing something as `sudo -u www-data rsync -avzR /var/www/dms/test/test.tif user@server.com:/mnt/myDir/`. In this case, be sure to read the [man page](http://ss64.com/bash/rsync_options.html) as `-R` can have some unexpected side-effects.

Comment: Thanks @shodanshok, thanks for your answer. I opetd for the answer 1. I think having tried the 3rd one but without success. Anyway, this works well now with the manual mkdir.